# Is there anyway I can get the robot view out of Choregraphe? read body for more specifics

Tags: pepper, nao-robot, choregraphe

My main goal is to create a website that when you open it, it shows the identical view that the Robot view has in Choregraphe (virtual robot and everything) and then you could send a behavior to the robot on that website and the robot would do the behavior. But I am trying to figure out if I can just get the robot view by itself. Like imagine opening Choregraphe but it opens with just the robot view (a view of the robot). Let me know if anyone has dealt with this, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No, the robot view is handled by a native program showing the view on your PC screen. Apart by capturing the screen, it is not designed to be redirected to a web page.

However NAO and Pepper robots are compatible with ROS, and you can setup web views showing any robot running ROS. I found [this online course that could teach you exactly how to do that](https://www.theconstructsim.com/robotigniteacademy_learnros/ros-courses-library/web-interfaces-for-ros-robots/).